# change or add list item class in a nested master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I get a null exception error on li.Attributes.Add("class", "current")

Master page:

```
<ul>
    <li id="li01"><a href="page1.aspx" title="Page 1">Page 1</a</li>
    <li id="li02"><a href="page2.aspx" title="Page 2">Page 2</a></li>
<ul>
```

Page Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim li As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Me.Page.Master.FindControl("li02"), System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove reference for the me.Page

Try following code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim li As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("li02"), System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "current")
    End Sub
```